# LoRa point-to-point connection receiving packets

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp32, lora, arduino-esp32

I would like to use LoRa (not LoRaWAN) to send a measurement from a LoRa device to a M5 Stack (esp32) with a LoRa module using a point-to-point connection.
Is it possible to save that measurement to a database (using WiFi) after it is received by the M5 Stack? Will I be able to access the content of the received packet by the M5 Stack?
Also, if this is possible, how many devices could send measurements to the M5 Stack?

Edit:
I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database. I'm already storing some data into the database using a normal M5 Stack, but I'm not sure whether it would work with the packets received from LoRa. I'm planning to use a LoRa temperature sensor. The message should contain the temperature measured, timestamp and battery level. The LoRa packet should be sent every 30 minutes.

Comment: Your question is very vague. You seem to want to send a measurement via LoRa, store it in a database and then access it. You don't mention how big the message is, nor how often it is sent, nor which database you mean, nor where that database is running nor how it is connected nor where you want to access it from...

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for your reply! I edited the question with some additional information.

Comment: That's looking better. Ok, so if you already know how to store other data in Firebase why do you imagine you will have any problems storing temperatures?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm worried about not being able to decrypt the packet received by the M5 Stack and I would like multiple thermometers to send packets to one M5 Stack, which I'm not sure is possible and if it is, how to distinguish between them.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention the temperatures were encrypted before. How are they encrypted? What is the sensor device you are using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I thought all LoRa devices send encrypted packets. At least as I've seen with the LoRaWAN devices they have to be connected to a service such as The Things Network, which decrypts the packets in order to get the message. I'm not sure, which device to use, because I don't know yet exactly how to use the point-to-point connection.